# In emacs org mode, is there a formula I can use to count the number of cells?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm new to emacs (spacemacs, actually) and org-mode. I'd like to have a final line in my table that shows how many rows there are in the table. Is there a formula function for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula should work: `vlen(@I..@II)`.

Example:

```
| Title |
|-------|
| one   |
| two   |
| three |
| four  |
|-------|
| 4     |
#+Tblfm: @6$1=vlen(@I..@II)
```

Answer (score 2):

the example above is specified as "@6" which requires you to know hte sum in advance.  The following seems to work:

```
| Title |
|-------|
| one   |
| two   |
| three |
| four  |
|-------|
| 4     |
#+Tblfm: @II$1=vlen(@I..@II)
```